Case Clause in Window Function
I have a situation here where I need to get the previous value using Window Function, I am able to do that, the problem is: I need to change the result based on current field.
The Example is here: JSFiddle
I'm almost there with:
SELECT *,      
       MAX(CASE WHEN TYPE_MOV = 1 THEN date END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) as prev_special_visit
FROM input
ORDER BY 1,2

But here, I hard-coded the TYPE_MOV as 1. But I need to get the previous date with the same TYPE_MOV. So, if the TYPE_MOV is 1 it gets the previous TYPE_MOV 1, if it's 2 it gets the previous TYPE_MOV 2 and so on.
How could I access the field outside the window function to compare? Something like:
SELECT *,      
       MAX(CASE WHEN INSIDE.TYPE_MOV = OUTSIDE.TYPE_MOV THEN date END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) as prev_special_visit
FROM input
ORDER BY 1,2

This a complement to this question

What's your desired output?

Sounds like you just need to partition also be TYPE_MOV https://sqlfiddle.com/postgresql/online-compiler?&id=8e1d7d57-3ed8-4f8d-8a87-be16bdf47499 but hard to say without proper sample data and expected results.

You should use LAG() Over() analytic function with a proper partition by and order by clause. It is not quite clear do you want previous date for TYPE_MOV only or for ID and TYPE_MOV. Below is code that gets both from sample data in your JSFiddle:
--      S Q L :
Select    id, date, type_mov,
          Lag(date) Over(Partition By id, type_mov Order By date) as prev_id_type_mov_date, 
          Lag(date) Over(Partition By type_mov Order By date) as prev_type_mov_date
From      input

/*      R e s u l t :
id  date        type_mov   prev_id_type_mov_date  prev_type_mov_date
--  ----------  ---------  ---------------------  -------------------    
A   2018-01-01  0          null                   null
A   2018-02-01  1          null                   null
A   2018-03-01  1          2018-02-01             2018-02-01
B   2018-01-02  0          null                   2018-01-01
B   2018-02-02  0          2018-01-02             2018-01-02
B   2018-03-02  1          null                   2018-03-01         */

The same logic and code is for next date per TYPE_MOV (or ID, TYPE_MOV) in which case use LEAD() Over() analytic function.
